# How can I fade player character when he goes inside or outside of the area?

Tags: unity, shaders

I want to fade the player when he goes out of the area.

For example, suppose a person enters a building. When a person is outside of the building, he shouldn't be seen, but when he enters he gradually becomes visible (using fading effect).

**when elephant is inside green area his alpha should be 1**

[image: photo_2019-04-15_07-21-39]

**when elephant is outside of green area his alpha should be 0**

[image: photo_2019-04-15_07-21-35]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use world space to fade your character.

> The object space (or object coordinate system) is specific to each
>   game object; however, all game objects are transformed into one common
>   coordinate system — the world space.
>
> If a game object is put directly into the world space, the
>   object-to-world transformation is specified by the Transform component
>   of the game object.
>
> https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cg_Programming/Unity/Shading_in_World_Space

## Fading by world space

[image: Record_2019_04_15_07_13_25_154]

```
Shader "Smkgames/worldSpaceFade" {
      Properties{
         _Size("Size",Vector) = (2,2,0,0)
      }
   SubShader {
      Pass {
         CGPROGRAM

         #pragma vertex vert  
         #pragma fragment frag 


         struct vertexInput {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
         };
         struct vertexOutput {
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            float4 position_in_world_space : TEXCOORD0;
         };

         vertexOutput vert(vertexInput input) 
         {
            vertexOutput output; 

            output.pos =  UnityObjectToClipPos(input.vertex);
            output.position_in_world_space = 
               mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, input.vertex);

            return output;
         }
         float2 _Size;

         float4 frag(vertexOutput input) : COLOR 
         {
             float3 world = input.position_in_world_space;

          float4 equation = pow(world.x/_Size.x,8) + pow(world.z/_Size.y,8);
          return smoothstep(1,0,equation);
         }

         ENDCG  
      }
   }
}
```

## Surface Shader

After understanding world space we can use it in our surface shader:

[image: Record_2019_04_15_07_14_24_876]

```
Shader "Smkgames/worldSpaceFade" {
    Properties {
         _Size("Size",Vector) = (2,2,0,0)
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Metallic ("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
    }
    SubShader {
 Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
     Pass {
        ZWrite On
        ColorMask 0
    }
        LOD 200

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows alpha:fade

        #pragma target 3.0

        sampler2D _MainTex;

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
            float3 worldPos: TEXCOORD2;
        };

        half _Glossiness;
        half _Metallic;
        fixed4 _Color;
        float2 _Size;

        void vert (inout appdata_full v, out Input o){
            UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(Input,o);
            o.worldPos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex);
        }


        UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(Props)
        UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(Props)

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
            fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
            float4 equation = pow(IN.worldPos.x/_Size.x,8) + pow(IN.worldPos.z/_Size.y,8);
            o.Albedo = c.rgb;
            o.Metallic = _Metallic;
            o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
            o.Alpha = smoothstep(1,0,equation);
        }
        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```